# Trigger Property IsMouseOver is not recognized or is not accessible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to set: "do nothing" when mouse is over button.
The part of code in XAML is:

```
<Button Name="dugme0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Click="dugme0_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/mystery_image.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

But problem is error in XAML file: The member "IsMouseOver" is not recognized or is not accessible.
How to fix that?

Comment: `<Style TargetType="Button">`

Comment: Thanks man! Now it's working.